# Set document height minus 100px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have the following code and instead of height(300), height() = document height-100

```
$(".bar").height(XXX);
```

Comment: @GraceShao where XXX is I would like the document height-100px so .bar is slightly shorter then the page

Comment: Read the docs, it tells you want to use http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Note that jQuery `height()` only applies to the element height not taking into account, padding, borders or margins. Only mentioning it just in case you thought it would be the total height of the element including padding, borders and margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var DocHeight = $(document).height();
$(".bar").height(DocHeight-100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var h = $(window).height() - 100;
$(".bar").height(h);
```

Comment: `$(window).height()` will get the height of the viewport. If you want the height of the actual HTML document and not the viewport you can use `$(document).height()` instead.